# Object of derived class inherited privately cannot access base class member function

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B
{
  public:
  int x;
  void print()
  {
    cout<<x;
  }
};

class D:private B
{
};

int main()
{
  D d;
  d.print();
}
```

Why can't I access print method ? Print method from `B` will be private property of `D` so it's logical that I should access it using object of `D`.
The error I'm getting is this:

> 'B' is not an accessible base of 'D'.

Comment: Private is private. Why do you think that you can access a private member  function? It is private after all, not public.

Comment: Aren't private member functions accessible within class ?

Comment: @AlokI, you're not accessing it within the class.

Comment: Guys please give me some link to read about this.

Comment: "Within the class," as you describe it, means that methods of the derived class can invoke the inherited method.  In your example, `main()` is not a method of any class, and in particular, it is not a method of class `D`.

Comment: @AlokI _"Guys please give me some link ...."_ Asking for 3rd party resource is off-topic here.

Comment: @AlokI "please give me some link" - these should do: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance , https://isocpp.org/faq

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is another good link.

Answer (score 2):

Private inheritance means that the base class is accessible only within the member functions of the derived class. In general you use private inheritance when you want to model a `has-a` relationship, not a `is-it`. It's not the case here, you are trying to directly call it in `main()`. This will work instead:

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
public:
    int x{42};
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
};

class D: private B
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        print(); // can access the private one in B
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.f();
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/232ce826b3759648)

You can read about it more here: [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/860339/3093378)

Or, as @WhozCraig mentioned, you can change the access via a `using` statement in the `public` section of your derived class:

```
using B::print; // now it is visible in the derived class
```

Comment: Or you could use `protected`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Hmm, imho `protected` inheritance should just be disallowed, it makes (complicated) things too complicated. I don't think anyone can come up with a killer example where `protected` inheritance is needed. Do you have one?

Comment: @vsoftco I tend to agree with you, but OP *could* solve his problem by making the member in the base class `protected` rather than private and then using public or protected inheritance to achieve his desired result (as I read it) of not allowing outside access but still having 'in-class' access in the derived class. I was going for a `protected:` member, not arguing specifically for 'protected inheritance' (which I agree is "icky" and not too useful).